# Drawing EKG graph and flashing light

Tags: java

Is it possible to draw EKG (electrocardiogram) graph and flashing light without using any container, if not what is the alternative?

Comment: and what is the format of the input data, and what is the output device, and where does the flashing light come in?

Comment: This question is quite vague.  To help us answer your question: What kind of system is this (desktop application, web application, embedded device, etc.)?  What frameworks are you using (GUI framework, web framework, etc.)?  What design do you have in mind?  What specifically do you want to know to help with that design?

Comment: some context might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to model a traditional oscilloscope display, I would extend [JPanel](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) rather than [Container](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html). An instance of [Timer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) is probably adequate for the required frame rate. The trace itself may be modeled with a FIFO [Queue](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) of co-ordinates that is shifted with each frame. It would be tempting to use a palette of varying brightness to simulate the trace, but I think using an [AlphaComposite](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html) offers greater fidelity.

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852) using `JFreeChart`.